# Getting s3 buckets limit with GO API

Tags: amazon-s3, bucket, quota

How do I get the s3 buckets quota limit by calling the GO API (default is 100 per account)?
I have tried serviceQuotas.GetServiceQuota(ctx, &servicequotas.GetServiceQuotaInput{
QuotaCode: "L-DC2B2D3D", ServiceCode: "s3"})
but the return value (serviceQuotaOutput) is nil. What am I missing here?
Thanks!

Comment: Service quotas are only available for non default values (or in some cases where it's been specifically set to a default value), you can call GetAWSDefaultServiceQuota if there is no quota set for a given property.

Comment: Let's say the quota limit was changed from default of 100 to 200. What api call I need to use to get the value of 200?

Comment: GetServiceQuota would return a result including 200 in that case.

Answer (score 1):

The AWS S3 bucket limit is 100. If you would like this to be extended the you will have to speak with support to do so.

Comment: Correct. Assuming the limit was increased, how do I know what is the current limit (via api)?